# Python3, beautifulsoup, return nothing in specific pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

In some pages, when I use beautifulsoup, return nothing...just blank pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

Site = "http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=parkbogum&page=2"
URL = Site
html = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

I can use beautifulsoup any other site except this site. and I dont know way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, this site is using cookies. You can see the headers in the browser's developer tool. You can get the cookie by following:

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
ck = r.getheader('Set-Cookie')
```

Now you can create the header like this and send it with subsequent requests.

```
headers = {                                                                                                                                                         
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": ck,                        
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36"
}

req = urllib.request.Request(URL, headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

Answer (score 1):

This URL will require certain headers passed while requesting. 
Pass this headers parameter while requesting the URL and you will get the HTML.

```
HTML = requests.get(URL , headers = headers).content
```

while

```
headers = {
"method":"GET",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36",
"Host":"gall.dcinside.com",
"Pragma":"no-cache",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some website servers look for robot scripts trying to access their pages. One of the simpler methods of doing this is to check to see which `User-Agent` is being sent by the browser. In this case as you are using Python and not a web browser, the following is being sent:

```
python-requests/2.18.4
```

When it sees an agent it does not like, it will return nothing. To get around this, you need to change the `User-Agent` string in your request. There are hundreds to choose from, as the agent string changes with each release of a browser. For example see this list of [Firefox User-Agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Firefox) e.g.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
```

The trick is to try a few, and find one that the server is happy with. In your case, ONLY the header needs to be changed in order to get HTML to be returned from the website. In some cases, cookies will also need to be used.

The header can be easily changed by passing a dictionary. This could be done using `requests` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=parkbogum&page=2"
html = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'}).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```